# Complicated conditional macro: force OR evaluation without latter definition existance

Tags: objective-c, import, macros, include, preprocessor

My service is included in 2 different platforms source files (`iOS` and `watchOS`), but I only want it to be compiled for `watchOS` platform only when a specified flag is set

- Under main platform (`iOS`): alway include content
- Under extension. Only include content when `BUILD_FLAG(watch_feature)` is `1`

`BUILD_FLAG` is defined in `config.h`. `config.h` is always available under `watchOS`, but *sometime* not available under `iOS` platform.

`TARGET_OS_IOS` is always available to detect which platform the file is included

What I want is something like

```
#include "config.h"
#if TARGET_OS_IOS || BUILD_FLAG(watch_feature)
  <content>
#endif
```

And *sometime* compiler complains `config.h` does not exist when compiling for `iOS` platform.

---

Here is my solution, but it is long. If anyone has better ideal, always welcome

Solution 1:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IOS
#if !defined(BUILD_FLAG)
#define MARKER
#define BUILD_FLAG(_) 1
#endif
#else
#include "config.h"
#endif

#if TARGET_OS_IOS || BUILD_FLAG(watch_feature)
#if defined(MARKER)
#undef MARKER
#undef BUILD_FLAG
#endif
  <file content>
#endif
```

Comment: `#import`? Are you sure this is C, and not Objective C?

Comment: whatever, they are equivalent, solution can use anything. I tagged `C` because it is more popular and I could not tagged more than 5 tags

Comment: @tranvansang Don't abuse tags.